# How to setup a server in Azure that requires all network traffic to go through an outbound Proxy?

Tags: azure, proxy

I need to setup a server running Windows Server 2016 in Azure where all network traffic is required to go through an outbound proxy server.

So my questions are:

- How to configure the network to do this?
- How to deploy a proxy server in Azure and then connect the two together?

Note that this is NOT a question about setting up a reverse proxy.  This is a question about setting up an outbound proxy server (a forward proxy).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing traffic through an outbound proxy can be done by creating a [route table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-route-table) in Azure and setting an appropriate route to send traffic to your proxy.

Azure does not currently offer a "Proxy Server as a Service", however there are lots of Proxy Server solutions in the [Azure Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?search=proxy&page=1) that you could look at.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!  Are there any suggestions you can provide on a simple route table rule to try, and also which of these marketplace things are actually outbound proxy servers (and not reverse proxy servers)?  Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The most commonly used proxy in that list would be Squid, but nearly all of those that come up are proxies, not reverse proxies (some can be used as both). The Azure route table would be fairly simple, you would just create a rule to forward all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to a virtual appliance, and provide the IP of the proxy server

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Would this result in a connection failure for attempts to connect out without going thru Proxy Server (desired behavior)?

Comment: If your default route (0.0.0.0/0) points to the proxy server then traffic will be routed through that. However if someone has rights to amend the routes or add a more specific route then they could get round it, so make sure you have permissions setup correctly